# How to localize page title using resource files (.resw)?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, .net-4.5

I need to translate the title of basic page in windows8 app. Here is a xaml string:

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Uid="title_select_profile" x:Key="AppName">Select profile</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
```

So, the trick with Uid doesn't work here. How to get accsess to this string from resource file?